# How to install libwebkit (libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0) in order to run CodeLite?

Tags: linux, centos, gtk, webkit

A pre-requisite for running codelite is WebKitGTK.

```
codelite: error while loading shared libraries: libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm on CentOS, so installing this is trivial.

```
# yum install webkitgtk.x86_64
```

This installs the library, but it does not install the file called `libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0` And that is my problem.  How do you get `libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0` installed?

I've run `updatedb` and `locate libwebkit` and that shows me this:

```
/usr/lib64/libwebkit-1.0.so.2
/usr/lib64/libwebkit-1.0.so.2.17.8
```

My machine is 64-bit.

What am I missing?  I want to get this file installed: `libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0`

Comment: Did you find a way to do it? I'm trying to install Rainlendar on RHEL 7 and I get the same error.

Comment: Back then, I put it down and did went a different direction -- However, I'm now on Fedora 23 and it has this missing module already installed.  `dnf provides libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0` shows webkitgtk-2.4.9-3.fc23.i686

Comment: try install webkitgtk2

Answer (score 1):

Almost all package managers have a subcommand that searches for files. RPM-based distros all have `rpm -q --whatprovides <neededfile>`, and yum has the slightly shorter `yum whatprovides <neededfile>`. Just do

```
yum whatprovides libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0
```

and `yum install` the package that provides it.